# Angular Javascript Concatenation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Good day!

I am trying to concatenate an HTML tag to my return message but it seems that it doesn't work for me.

My controller code (if API returns that the account does not exist - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFbIX.png)):

```
$scope.posts = 'No account found.' + '<a href="">Apply now</a>';
```

And the output is:

[image: html view]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you would [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).  However, I would recommend reviewing what it is you are doing and considering whether it might not be better achieved by taking that markup and putting it in an `ng-hide` wrapped element that only shows when no account is found.

*PS- it is customary to include your code as text, rather than as an image.  That way it is easier to copy/paste it into the solution for clearer examples. Welcome to StackOverflow-- happy coding!*

Comment: Thanks for this @anied. This works perfectly! But first, it needs to include the santize.js in script src to work. Again, Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! ! !